# Unity won't start on login

Tags: unity, compiz, nvidia, gnome-classic

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 on 2 laptops today. One of a friend, and one of my own. Both have NVidia graphics cards.

This went the same on both computers. When you login the first time you get a message wich is basically telling you to install the NVidia drivers.

However, when I restarted after installing the new driver on my friend's laptop, Unity just worked.

When I installed the drivers on my laptop, and rebooted, it just booted straight back into the Ubuntu Classic desktop environment.

In the sessions list at the login screen, there are the following items: *Ubuntu*, *Ubuntu Classic*, *Ubuntu Classic (no effects)*, *User defined*, *Recovery console*. I haven't touched this setting, as it seems to me that *Ubuntu* should be correct.
Appart from that when I login I still get the Ubuntu Classic environment (without the message telling me that Unity couldn't be started)
When I run `compiz --replace` manually, I get the Unity interface... **but it instantly freezes**.

So why doesn't it start the Unity interface? My graphics card is an Nvidia Quadro NVS 110M, wich has always worked fluently with Compiz Fusion.

Comment: have you tried reinstalling unity; it may 'repair' your ubuntu session?

Comment: As to be expected, this did not solve the problem. Neither did updating Unity, wich I didn't do before because I'm on vacation and the wireless internet is.... let's just say it's crap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar AU Question with your Graphics Card is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49603/dell-d820-nvidia-compiz-crashes-wont-run).

I would suggest follow the same advice - go to your Hardware Drivers window.  Deactivate the `nvidia-current` driver and try installing the `nvidia-173` driver.

Comment: Well, that's one step in the right direction... Now at least Unity works when I run `compiz --replace`. However, the Gnome Panels are still there as well. So it would be nice if Unity would automatically start on login (session: `Ubuntu`), and the Gnome Panels would go away.

Comment: By the way, `compiz --replace` does seem to return an awful lot of errors. Don't know if it will help you but here's the output of `compiz --replace --debug`: http://pastebin.com/sN2NShw8

Comment: try installing/reinstalling unity-place-applications and unity-place-files packages

Comment: I installed all updates (appart from the kernel updates), rebooted, reinstalled `unity-place-applications` and `unity-place-files`, rebooted again, and it went straight into the classic Ubuntu desktop again... Running `compiz --replace` also still gives me a working Unity interface... but on top of my Gnome panels...

I believe there was something in `gconf` to not make the panel load anymore (wich I used with Avant Window Navigator), but I can't find it anymore. Also, uninstalling `gnome-panel` doesn't seem to me like it's a very good thing to do.

Comment: what happens if you do a unity --reset  ?  if it doesnt work on its own, you may have to reset compiz - use this link to help. http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-reset-unity-launcher-icons-or.html

Comment: I've already fuxed the problem of the Unity interface starting on top of the Gnome Panel myself. I added `compiz --replace` to the startup applications to start Unity, and made sure that the Gnome Panel was unable to start.... by removing `/usr/bin/gnome-panel` xD Not really a friendly way to do it, but it works :p
I'm going to mark your answer as accepted because you seem to have identified the problem correctly.